# How to authorize Google App Engine in Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to authorize a Google App Engine project into Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL). I can't find a way to do it in the 'Authorization' tab in the instance of Cloud SQL. It only asks me to provide an IP address but I'm not sure if we can really get the IP address of App Engine.

Any suggestion on how to authorize an App Engine project in Cloud SQL?

[Authorization tab for Cloudsql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIGzT.png)

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using App Engine Standard in the same project than your CloudSQL instance, your app is already authorized to access it.
- If you are using the Flexible environment or your app is in a different project, then you'll need to authorize the App Engine's service account by adding it to IAM in the CloudSQL's project and give it the appropriate permissions (Cloud SQL Client or Editor role).

You'll find detailed information [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine).

Comment: Thank you LundinCast. I think I have followed that doc earlier, so in my case both app & cloud sql were part of same GCP project. The thing I would like to highlight here is that, I am connecting to cloudsql using the node module 'pg-promise' via the connection string instead of going by "Knex" because my project were already written using the pg-promise module. would that really matters?

Comment: Just to update this thread, so I navigated to Instances section of app engine and specified those VM instance IP's into the authorization section of cloud sql and my app seems to be able to connect with cloudsql using my old node module pg-promise.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an IP address of the App Engine is indeed not the way to go. You can only provide IP addresses of current instances of your engine which can be killed and replaced by different instances with new addresses at any time.

Try to follow the tutorial on setting up the App Engine closely from the beginning. I attach a link to a resource about Django as it was applicable in my case https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

In order to connect your App Engine to a Cloud SQL instance within one project, you only have to adjust configuration files in your application. In case of Django, your settings.py and app.yaml file have to be correctly configured. Make sure the database host in settings.py is in the following format, ['HOST'] = '/cloudsql/{your-cloudsql-connection-string}' and that app.yaml includes
"beta_settings: cloud_sql_instances: {your-cloudsql-connection-string}".

You can refer to the sample code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql). Note that [Google Cloud platform Git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform) also contains samples for other environments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide excerpts of the parts you think are relevant from the links you provided in your answer? If those pages ever change your answer then loses its usefulness.